# Using MSAL, on directory's instead of subdomains

Tags: angular, msal.js

Running into an issue where we have 2 web applications (Angular) [www.example.com/app1](http://www.example.com/app1) and [www.example.com/app2](http://www.example.com/app2) and becouse they are on the same origin domain when Microsofts MSAL generates tokens it breaks the other application.

Since we dont have the option to easily use subdomains, I have wrote a script to attempt to get the correct token for said application from local storage. But it doesn't seem to work perfect, Anyone else ran into this?